# Android get SSID of currently connected wifi network

Tags: android, string, wifi, ssid

Several people have asked questions regarding getting the SSID, all of them only partionly work. According to the Android API wifiInfo.getSSID() should return a string, but no matter what I do the if statement returns false. I want to check if my phone is connected to "DieKantankys"

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) getSystemService(WIFI_SERVICE);
    WifiInfo wifiInfo = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();

    //Log.d("wifiInfo", wifiInfo.toString());
    //Log.d("NetworkId",wifiInfo.getNetworkId());

    if(wifiInfo.getSSID()=="DieKantankys"){
        setContentView(R.layout.group_choose_activity);
    }else{
        setContentView(R.layout.not_connected_to_scouting_wifi_error);
    }

}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> but no matter what I do the if statement returns false.

At first, when you are comparing Strings, you have to use [equals()](http://www.leepoint.net/notes-java/data/expressions/22compareobjects.html) because you want to compare values and not references:

```
if (wifiInfo.getSSID().equals("DieKantankys")) {
   // do your stuff
}
```

For that reason it did't work for you. Your current scenario will always return **false** because you're comparing String references with `==`

**Note:** Sometimes is very "handy" to use [equalsIgnoreCase()](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_equalsignorecase.htm) - with an usage of this method, comparison is case-insensitive.